# Find the largest interval of non intersecting roads

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, time-complexity

This is a problem I'm stuck trying to solve.

Assume you have 2 major roads A and B that run parallel to each other.
Now we have a set of roads R, that all have one endpoint on A and the other endpoint at B.
None of the roads in R share an endpoint in either road.  So if there r Roads in R, then there are 2r distinct endpoints. 
Other than that, these roads can stretch however long, go diagonal, parallel or whatever direction they please as long as the begin and end at the A and B rados
Assume we can check if 2 roads intersect in O(1) time.

Q1) Find the largest continuous subset of roads in R in which no two roads intersect that don't intersect. This algorithm should run in O(n log n)

Q2) Same as Q1 but now we'll assume that the 2r distinct endpoints lie on a unit circle given by x<sup>2</sup> + y<sup>2</sup>  = 1

This algorithm should run in O(n<sup>3</sup>) or less.

My approaches so far
I tried sorting the  roads by the minimum of the 2 endpoints for q1, so that we have the roads starting at the most left in the beginning. 
Then I would iterate through them, and and check only if the roads whose min of their two end points begin after the iterating road's min endpoint and slash off those roads and recursively call the function again.

But I'm not sure how this works. And I'm not sure if its O(n log n)

For q2 i have no idea.

I have a feeling this can be done by dynamic programming and I'm missing some sort of data structure with which I could solve this easily.
Please help.

Comment: What do you mean by "continuous subset". Does R have some kind of natural ordering? (e.g., road number 1 goes from a to b, road number 2 from c to d, etc.)

Comment: It isnt specified what the actual input ordering is. But lay it out visually, and we can see the roads going from left to right. In this ordering, we have to find the largest interval of non intersecting roads.

Comment: So an exact statement would be something like: find the largest maximal subset S of R such that no road in R-S intersects any road in S ? But what does "continuous" mean in Q2?

Comment: http://imgur.com/Ril4We1  I have marked the largest interval

Comment: "Q1) .... in which no two roads intersect that don't intersect." Huh? If they don't intersect, then... well... they don't intersect...

Comment: My previous comment also seems to be wrong, one should add something like: largest such subset not separated to many parts by (possibly intersecting) roads EDIT: ok. forget about it, see OP's comment on accepted answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### QUESTION 1

You have N endpoints on road A, and N endpoints on road B.

Sort the roads in R based on their first endpoint, and prepare a list A of their second endpoints.

So for example, if we have roads:

```
1->10
8->7
5->6
```

we would sort these by the first endpoint into:

```
1->10
5->6
8->7
```

and prepare a list A with the second endpoints:

```
A = [10,6,7]
```

Finding the largest subset of non-overlapping roads is equivalent to finding the longest increasing sequence in this array.

Finding [longest increasing subsequence](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Longest_increasing_subsequence) is a standard algorithm with an O(nlogn) solution.

In this case, the longest increasing subsequence is [6,7] of length 2, so the answer is 2.

[image]

Comment: but if a road goes from 1 to 10 between the 2 major roads,
roaads 5->6,8->7 has to intersect with road 1->10 right?
so then no roads in this example is non intersecting

Comment: If the answer to my example is not 2, then I have misunderstood your question.  Perhaps you could add an example or two to the question to help me understand correctly?

Comment: http://imgur.com/5KBxgtG  
In that image c and d would be the largest interval.
Sorry if i didnt word the question properly